# How to run an ASP.NET project from a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

A friend of mine gave me a 10 years old website to rebuild from scratch. He gave me the root directory that was on a windows server. The problem is that I would like to test it at home and I don't know how to do so ! Thanks you for your help !

Here is the tree :

```
.
├── Print_contacts.aspx
├── Print_contacts.apsx.cs
├── Print_friends.aspx
├── Print_friends.aspx.cs
├── Default.apsx
├── Default.aspx.cs
├── Logo.png
├── MasterPage.master
├── MasterPage.master.cs
├── NewDesign.master
├── NewDesign.master.cs
├── stylesheet.css
├── web.config
├── Add
│   └── Add_contact.aspx
│   └── Add_contact.aspx.cs
│   └── Add_friend.aspx
│   └── Add_friend.aspx.cs
├── App_Data
    └── db.mdb
```

Comment: You could make a shared folder to simulate a Network drive.  The access like a network drive using \\Your computer name\shared folder name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a ASP.NET application.

1. In Visual Studio, create a new empty ASP.NET project.
2. Include the files into the project (copy the files into the project directory and then include them from Visual Studio)
3. Run the project

Another way of testing the project, without Visual Studio, would be to create an application in IIS pointing to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example copy the sources, start a new ASP.NET Project in your Visual Studio with copied sources and run it.